# Finding an area of sub-part of a circle

Tags: geometry

I believe this image describes what I am trying to solve:

[image: Description]

Given the circle with radius $r$ and the value of the area $s=S_{ADC}$, I need to figure out what are the coordinates of point $C$ (find the values of $CD$ and $DO$), or find the value of the $x$ angle. As you can see from the picture - $AOB$ angle is the right angle.

The area $S_{AOB}=\frac{1}{4}\pi r^2$. So the following equation is valid:

$$\frac{1}{4}\pi r^2 - s = xr+\frac{1}{2}cos(x)sin(x)r^2=xr+\frac{1}{4}sin(2x)r^2$$

And this is as far as I could take it.

I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$S_{AOC}=\frac12r^2\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)=s+\frac12 r \,DO\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)=s+\frac12 r^2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)$$

then indicating with $\alpha=\frac{\pi}2-x$

$$\frac12r^2\alpha=s+\frac14 r^2\sin2\alpha\implies \sin 2\alpha=2\alpha-\frac{4s}{r^2}$$

which can be solved by numerical methods.

Comment: @GSazheniuk we can use that $DO=r\cos(\pi/2-x)$

Comment: Ok, I feel bad that I didn't know that cos(x)*sin(x) = 1/2*sin(2x). It looks like this is something very basic. I still have bad time trying to figure out what to do with this equation. I even tried to subtract your equation from mine but it didn't make any sense. I feel like I am missing something very simple here. Sorry, but can I get another hint? :)

Comment: Sorry to bother, but could you please help me with this one? I really don't know how to solve this equation. P.S. I don't know why, but I can't tag you in the comments, probably I need some more reputation to do that?

Comment: @GSazheniuk I've edited for a typo. I didn't try to solve that but it seems hard to find an explicit solution, I think we need a numerical method to solve for x. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ s= \int _{-r} ^D \sqrt {r^2-x^2}dx $$

Solve for D and you have $DO$ figured out.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I was never taught how to solve integral equations.